# jQuery Slider Bullet navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have created a slider in jQuery, CSS and HTML.

It uses arrows and bullets to navigate as well as an autoplay system.

The problem I am having is: I would like the slider to change the slide that is displayed when the user clicks the respective bullet (i.e. bullet 1 slide 1 etc.) However when the user clicks the bullets, nothing happens.

I have tried using alerts to identify where the code is failing but it seems that the `$('.bullet').click(function(){})` is not even called when clicking `<span class="bullet">`.

The error seems to occur because the bullets are auto generated. I don't understand why.

Here's a fiddle for everyone: http://jsfiddle.net/TczNn/7/

This is the code:

```
<!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
        <div id="content">

            <!-- BEGIN CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW -->
            <div id="top-slide">
                <div class="wrapper">

                <!-- BEGIN CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW SLIDES -->
                    <div id="slide0" class="slide">
                        <h2>Your Site... Defined</h2>
                        <h4>With D&amp;D there is no inbetween, we will never compromise your requirements.</h4>
                    </div>  

                    <div id="slide1" class="slide">
                        <h2>Your Site... Defined 2</h2>
                        <h4>With D&amp;D there is no inbetween, we will never compromise your requirements.</h4>
                    </div>                     

                    <div id="slide2" class="slide">
                        <h2>Your Site... Defined 3</h2>
                        <h4>With D&amp;D there is no inbetween, we will never compromise your requirements.</h4>
                    </div>                     
                <!-- END CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW SLIDES -->

                </div>

                <div id="numSlides">3</div>

                <div class="arrows">
                    <span class="arrow left"></span>
                    <span class="arrow right"></span>
                </div>
                <div id="select">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div class="bullets">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <!-- END CONTENT TOP SLIDESHOW -->
    </div>
```

CSS:

```css
/*====================================================
    D&D Creative Solutions
    ----------------------------------------------
        Explore D&D Creative - v1.0
        Date: 30/11/2012
        Stylesheet By: David Passmore
        StandAlone
    ----------------------------------------------
© D&D Creative Solutions - All Rights Reserved
====================================================*/

/*============================================
    ENABLE FONTS
============================================*/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700);

body {
    font-family:"PT Sans";
    font-size:13px;
}

/*============================================
    LINKS
============================================*/
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#CCCCCC;
    -moz-transition: color 150ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: color 150ms ease-out;
}

/*============================================
    LAYOUT
============================================*/
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header .wrapper, #footer .wrapper {
    width:1100px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both !important;
    float:none !important;
}

/*============================================
    HEADER
============================================*/
#header {
    position:fixed;
    height:55px;
    line-height:55px;
    background-color:#3D3B37;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:9999;
}

#header .wrapper ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header .wrapper ul > li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 8px;
}

#header .wrapper div.main-nav {
    float:right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
}

#header .wrapper div.top-logo {
    float:left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:16px;
    width:126px;
    height:55px;
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/common/header/logo-new.png) center no-repeat;
}

/*
#header .wrapper div.main-nav ul li.separator {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/common/header/header-nav-sep.png) center no-repeat;
    width: 5px;
    height: 55px;
}
*/

#header .wrapper div.main-nav ul li.separator {
    line-height:53px;
}

#header .wrapper div.main-nav ul li {
    color:#CCCCCC;
}

#header .wrapper div.main-nav ul li a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#header .wrapper div.main-nav ul li.active {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

/*============================================
    CONTENT
============================================*/
#content {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-top:55px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

/*============================================
    FOOTER
============================================*/
#footer {
    background-color:#3D3B37;
    color:#CCCCCC;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:10px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#footer .wrapper > div {
    float:left;
    margin-left:50px;
}

#footer .wrapper div.links ul li a:hover {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#footer .wrapper div.social {
    float:right;
    margin-left:0;
}

#footer .wrapper div > ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#footer .wrapper div ul > li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 8px;
}

#footer .wrapper div.links ul li.separator {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/common/footer/footer-nav-sep.png) top no-repeat;
    width: 5px;
    height: 17px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

/*============================================
    HOME.PHP
============================================*/
#home #content #top-slide {
    background-color:#3D3B37;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#home #content #top-slide .slide {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    left:-1000px;
}

#home #content #top-slide .wrapper {
    position:relative;
}

#home #content #top-slide #numSlides{
    visibility: hidden;
}

#home #content #top-slide h2, #home #content #top-slide h4 {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
}

#home #content #top-slide h2 {
    margin:60px 0 0 0;
    font-size:36px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #1F1E1C;
}

#home #content #top-slide h4 {
    margin:150px 0 0 0;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #1F1E1C;
}

#home #content #top-slide .arrows {
    width:1100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#home #content #top-slide .arrows span.arrow {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    width:25px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40%;
}

#home #content #top-slide .arrows span.arrow.left {
    background-position:left;
    left:0;
}

#home #content #top-slide .arrows span.arrow.right {
    background-position:right;
    right:0;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select {
    height:48px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/bg-slie-select.png) repeat;
    display:none;
    line-height:48px;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select span.bullet {
    height:48px;
    width:25px;
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/bullets.png) no-repeat right;
    line-height:48px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select span.bullet:hover {
    background-position:center;
}

#home #content #top-slide #select span.bullet.selected {
    background-position:left;
}

#home #content #twitter-main {
    background-color:#cccccc;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding-top:30px;
    text-align:center;
}

#home #content #twitter-main i.icon-twitter {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/common/social/twitter.png) no-repeat center;
    width:37px;
    height:37px;
    margin:0px auto 20px auto;
    display:block;
}

#home #content #twitter-main span.divider {
    border-top:1px solid #535353;
    height:0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#home #content #twitter-main h2.feed {
    margin:40px 0;
}

#home #content #twitter-main p.info {
    font-size:10px;
    color:#666666;
}

#home #content #services {
    height:500px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    background:#DDDDDD;
    padding-top:20px;
}

#home #content #services .wrapper > h2{
    margin-top:0px;
    font-size:24px;
}

#home #content #services .cols .col {
    margin:0 50px;
    float:left;
    width:233px;
    text-align:center;
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/services-c-c.png) no-repeat top;
    height:260px;
    padding-top:170px;
}

#home #content #services .cols #ac.col {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/services-c-ac.png) no-repeat top;
}

#home #content #services .cols #sup.col {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/services-c-support.png) no-repeat top;
}

#home #content #services .cols #qu.col {
    background:url(http://new.dpwebdev.co.uk/business-sites/explore-d-and-d/media/img/home/services-c-qu.png) no-repeat top;
}

#home #content #services .cols .col span.divider {
    border-top:1px solid #3D3B37;
    height:0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
/*============================================
    STAFF.PHP
============================================*/
#staff #content #top-content {
    background-color:#3D3B37;
    height:300px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}

#staff #content #top-content h1 {
    font-size:36px;
}

#staff #content #top-content span.divider {
    border-top:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    height:0;
    width:400px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/*============================================
    STAFF.PHP
============================================*/

#contact #content #top-content {
    background-color:#3D3B37;
    height:300px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}

#contact #content #top-content h1 {
    font-size:36px;
}

#contact #content #top-content span.divider {
    border-top:2px solid #FFFFFF;
    height:0;
    width:400px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

​
JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    //HOME.PHP
    $('#home #top-slide').bind("mouseenter", function(){
      $('#select').stop(true).fadeIn(600);
    });

    $('#home #top-slide').bind("mouseleave", function(){
      $('#select').stop(true).fadeOut(600);
    });




    //HOME.PHP - SLIDER

    function mainSlider() {
        var numsliders;
        var currentSlider = 0;
        var interval;
        var slideWidth;

        $('#slider0').css('opacity', 1);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            numsliders = parseInt($('#numSlides').html());
            generateBullets();
            $('#slide0').css('left', '0px');
            $('#slide0').css('height', '300px');
            $('#slide0').css('width', '1000px');
            $('#slide0').css('top', '0px');
            $('#slide0').css('opacity', '1');
            $('#slide0').addClass("showing");
            slideWidth = $('#slide0').width();
        });

        function nextSlider() {
            specificSlider((currentSlider + 1) % numsliders);
        }

        interval = window.setInterval(nextSlider, 7000);

        //arrow, bullet and autoplay functions




        function previousSlider() {
            if (currentSlider !== 0) {
                specificSlider((currentSlider - 1));
            }
        }

        function generateBullets() {
            var $bullet = $('#select .bullets');

            for (var i = 0; i < numsliders; i++) {
                $bullet.append('<span class="bullet" id="' + i + '"></span>');
            }

            $('.bullets #0').addClass("selected");
        }

        //call arrow functions
        $('span.arrow.left').click(function() {
            previousSlider();
        });

        $('span.arrow.right').click(function() {
            nextSlider();
        });

        //call bullet functions
        $('.bullet').click(function() {

            var $id = $(this).attr("id");

            specificSlider($id);
        });


        function specificSlider(sliderNumber) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);

            // move the next slider on deck
            $('#slider' + sliderNumber).css('left', $('#top-slide').css('width'));
            $('#slider' + sliderNumber).css('top', '0px');
            $('#slider' + sliderNumber).css('height', '300px');
            $('#slider' + sliderNumber).css('width', '1000px');

            // move old slide off, 
            $('#slide' + currentSlider).animate({
                left: '-1020px',
                top: '0px',
                height: '300px',
                width: '1000px',
                opacity: 0
            }, 900, null);
            $('#slide' + currentSlider).removeClass("showing");
            $('.bullets #' + currentSlider).removeClass("selected");

            // new slide on
            $('#slide' + sliderNumber).animate({
                left: '0px',
                height: '300px',
                width: '1000px',
                top: '0px',
                opacity: 1
            }, 900, null);
            $('#slide' + sliderNumber).addClass("showing");
            $('.bullets #' + sliderNumber).addClass("selected");

            currentSlider = sliderNumber;

            interval = window.setInterval(nextSlider, 7000);
        }
    }

    //initalise slider 
    mainSlider();

});​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the **span** with bullet class dynamically .. So the normal click event will not work.. You need to **delegate the event** to a static parent..

```
$('.bullet').click(function() {
```

supposed to be

```
$('body').on('click','.bullet' ,function() {
```